# rails3inaction sending to gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've been going through Rails 3 in action, the section on sending real email. When I run the feature to send an email to my gmail account, I receive the mail, but the from address is set as also my gmail, not `ticketee@gmail.com`. I do have the default :from setup as well:

```
  class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "ticketee@gmail.com"

    def comment_updated(comment, user)
      @comment = comment
      @user = user
      mail from: "ticketee@gmail.com", to: user.email, subject: "[ticketee] #{comment.ticket.project.name} - #{comment.ticket.title}"
    end
  end
```

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

**Edit**

Changed the above from address to just be my gmail, which I no longer get nil as the test response. However, it seems to be running into a different issue:

```
Then there should be an email from Ticketee in my box               # features/step_definitions/app_email_steps.rb:20
      deadlock; recursive locking (ThreadError)
      <internal:prelude>:8:in `lock'
      <internal:prelude>:8:in `synchronize'
      ./features/step_definitions/app_email_steps.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
      <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
      ./features/step_definitions/app_email_steps.rb:21:in `/^there should be an email from Ticketee in my box$/'
      features/gmail.feature:32:in `Then there should be an email from Ticketee in my box'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/gmail.feature:20 # Scenario: Receiving a real-world email
```

Answer (score 1):

Author of the book here.

The `default :from` line is a mistake. You are unable to set the from address for the emails because GMail will enforce it. You can still set a display name for the email, I think:

```
default from: "From Ticketee, with love <thecorrectemail@gmail.com>"
```

Comment: Thanks ryan, I gave that a try, but no go. I then just used my gmail address. But as explained above in my edits, I seem to be receiving another error. Should I perhaps try a different gmail gem version or something?

Comment: Ah, the deadlock recursive error... That happens sometimes. I haven't yet investigated why it happens or how to fix it sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I change the step to this and it work

```
@mails =  @gmail.inbox.find(:unread,from: "didahsutest@gmail.com")
@mails.each do |mail|
    if  mail.subject =~ /^\[ticketee\]/
        @received_mail = true
    end
    @received_mail.should be_true
end
```

but I have to remove `mail.delete!`

Because I got this error

```
Label '[Gmail]/Trash' doesn't exist! (Gmail::Message::NoLabelError)
```